# Как создать N дубликатов строк в DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть DataFrame, во втором столбце которого, каждая строка содержит какое-то значение. Нужно добавить N строк в промежутки с этим значение, то есть, как-бы "раскатать" значения на большее количество строк.

```
2015.08.07  98
2015.08.07  194
2015.08.07  116
2015.08.07  118
2015.08.07  127
2015.08.07  113
2015.08.07  81
```

Например на 3:

```
2015.08.07  98
2015.08.07  98
2015.08.07  98
2015.08.07  194
2015.08.07  194
2015.08.07  194
2015.08.07  116
2015.08.07  116
2015.08.07  116
2015.08.07  118
2015.08.07  118
2015.08.07  118
2015.08.07  127
2015.08.07  127
2015.08.07  127
2015.08.07  113
2015.08.07  113
2015.08.07  113
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исходный фрейм:

```
In [39]: df
Out[39]:
         col1  col2
0  2015.08.07    98
1  2015.08.07   194
2  2015.08.07   116
3  2015.08.07   118
4  2015.08.07   127
5  2015.08.07   113
6  2015.08.07    81

In [40]: df.dtypes
Out[40]:
col1    object
col2     int64
dtype: object
```

решение:

```
import numpy as np

res = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, 3, axis=0), columns=df.columns).astype(df.dtypes)
```

результат:

```
In [42]: res
Out[42]:
          col1  col2
0   2015.08.07    98
1   2015.08.07    98
2   2015.08.07    98
3   2015.08.07   194
4   2015.08.07   194
5   2015.08.07   194
6   2015.08.07   116
7   2015.08.07   116
8   2015.08.07   116
9   2015.08.07   118
10  2015.08.07   118
11  2015.08.07   118
12  2015.08.07   127
13  2015.08.07   127
14  2015.08.07   127
15  2015.08.07   113
16  2015.08.07   113
17  2015.08.07   113
18  2015.08.07    81
19  2015.08.07    81
20  2015.08.07    81

In [43]: res.dtypes
Out[43]:
col1    object
col2     int64
dtype: object
```